# SXA: Renderings disappearing from Available Renderings

Tags: sxa

When I am adding available renderings into SXA, they do show in the Experience Editor's toolbox but after a some time, they disappear (only one stays permanently in the folder, and it has the same configuration as others !).

Here are the steps I followed to add my renderings,

1. Create a folder in Renderings hosting all my custom renderings
2. For each rendering in the folder, create a controller rendering inheriting from Standard Controller, the repository inherits from ModelRepository, the model from RenderingModelBase
3. Create an available renderings item in Presentation/Available Renderings
4. Add renderings to the renderings field.

After having noticed the first disappearances, I also tried to follow [Gatogordo's tutorial](https://ggullentops.blogspot.fr/2017/04/how-add-custom-rendering-SXA-Sitecore.html), with no more luck.

Did I do something wrong ? Has anybody experienced the same issue ? Any clue is welcome !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have experienced something similar and we discovered that this has to do with the fact that when we were syncing the items, sometimes the checkbox would get unchecked. Make sure that *Editable* is checked on the *Rendering Controller*.

Answer (score 0):

I also have same issue with the toolbox is not updating with aviailable rendering components. 
Some how i unchecked the  rendering "Editable" checkbox got. I checked the checkbox and started working.